# how to align all my li on one column?

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/cg578trx/10/

```css
.test {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>aa</li>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaa</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

```
Output
       * a
      * aaa
     * aaaaa
    * aaaaaaa
   * aaaaaaaaa

Desired Output

       * a
       * aaa
       * aaaaa 
       * aaaaaaa
       * aaaaaaaaa
```

I want to align all my li items in one column. I used display:inline-block but not working. How can I fix? Thank you.

Comment: simply remove text-align:center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center the whole list, switch `text-align` back to `left` in the `<ul>`, and make it `display: inline-block` to center in the `<div>` as a whole.

```css
.test {
  text-align:center;
}

.test > ul {
  text-align: left;
  list-style-position: inside;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>aaaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaaaaaa</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You could remove `list-style-position: inside` depending on your styling, as it's not necessary to center the list.

Answer (score 0):

I used flexbox. `display: flex; justify-content: center` ensures children are aligned vertically to center.

If you are new to flexbox I recommend [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

You can read more how `text-align` works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).

#### Snippet

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.test ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>aa</li>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaa</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: I want the text in the middle.

Comment: please avoid editing the question to simply transform code to snippet ... he clearly said he's using Bootstrap, so the snippet you made is irrelevant and make the question even worse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180743/white-space-on-top-and-bottom-of-html-page-using-bootstrap

Comment: Could you please explain to me why snippet is worse than pure code? If he's using bootstrap he should have imported it into his snippet, so we can reproduce the issue. SO's snippets are preferable way of inserting HTML / CSS / JS small portions of code. Even after your re-edit someone edited it once again to snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Remove `text-align: center;` Its Work

```css
.test {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>aa</li>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaa</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the text in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```css
.test {
  list-style-position: inside;

}

.test ul{
display:table; 
margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>aa</li>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaa</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use      `display:flex;`
     `justify-content: center;` instead of `text-align: center;` and use  `:before` to change dots to `*`

```css
.test li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.test li:before {
  content: "*";
  position: absolute;
  left: -13px;
  top: 4px;
}

.test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>aaaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaaaa</li>
    <li>aaaaaaaaa</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @tom clack see how to chang dot to *